# Control should switch automatically after the user is done entering the text in UITextField

Tags: iphone, uitextfield

In my app i have two textfields and i want the control from one text field to switch to second control as soon as the user is done entering the values in the first textfield automatically.

Does anybody has any idea on this?

Thanks,

Comment: I'd just have a verification when a certain requirement is met in your first textview, then just call `[textView2 becomeFirstResponder];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume "done entering" means the user hits return, ... button on keyboard.

UITextField has delegate with UITextFieldDelegate protocol. And here's method ...

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
```

... you can implement it in this way ...

```
...
self.myFirstTextField.delegate = self;
self.mySecondTextField.delegate = self;
...

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
  if ( textField == self.myFirstTextField ) {
    // User hits return key on keyboard when editing first textfield
    [mySecondTextField becomeFirstResponder];
  } else if ( textField == self.mySecondTextField ) {
    // User hits return key on keyboard when editing second textfield
    // This simply removes focus from the second textfield and hides keyboard
    [mySecondTextField resignFirstResponder];
  }
  return YES;
}
```

If "done entering" is not return, ... button on keyboard, you can implement this delegate's method ...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

... to check UITextField's text when user did type.